# Checking two events in one html tag

Tags: javascript

I want to check two things in the form, one is onclick and the other "enter" function. So that, alert will be used by clicking the button or pressing "enter". But, "enter" function is not working(There is no problem with "onclick"). Where is the problem? Codes;

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter something in the box: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)" onKeyDown="keyevent(event)">
</FORM>


Javascript    

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
}
function keyevent(e)
        {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) 
          var TestVar2 = form.inputbox.value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar2);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The event onKeyPress should be add to the textbox to call keyevent function to check for enter key. Here is a quick sample from your code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
  var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
  alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
}
function keyevent(form, e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var TestVar2 = form.inputbox.value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar2);
  }
}
</SCRIPT>

<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter something in the box: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="" onkeypress="keyevent(this.form, event)"><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)" onKeyDown="keyevent(event)">
</FORM>
```

You might also want to add onSubmit="return false;" in the form tag to prevent the form to be submitted user press enter key in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you could try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    Enter something in the box: <br />
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="">
    <input type="button" id="button1" Value="Click">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputbox = null;
        var button1 = null;

        var keyEvent = function(event) {
            if(13 == event.keyCode) {
                alert("you've typed: " + inputbox.val());
                return false;
            }
        };  

        var button1_Click = function(event) {
            if('' != inputbox.val()) {
                alert("you've typed: " + inputbox.val());
            }
        };

        $(function() {

            inputbox = $("#inputbox");
            button1 = $("#button1");

            inputbox.keypress(keyEvent);
            button1.bind('click', button1_Click);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```